# Ember JS - JSON api string data need to be deserialized in table format

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Can anyone from Ember Expert help me? How can I display the JSON api data I am getting in table format?

I am getting the below data in my model. However It's coming in normal paragraph.

```
"table": "Fee Details\tEntrance/Joining Fees\n 1000\n20000"
```

I want the table structure in 2 rows & 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to HTML structure as following,

var test  = "table": "Fee Details\tEntrance/Joining Fees\n 1000\n20000";

var newDiv = jQuery('').html(test)

console.log(jQuery(newDiv)[0].innerText);